# ASP.NET Javascript Textbox onblur

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having some problems getting a javascript registered on the page so my textbox can fire it on onBlur. I have created a simple test page to demonstrate my problem.

Here is the backend VB.Net

```
Public Class Test
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim scriptText As String = ""
    scriptText &= "<script language='javascript'>"
    scriptText &= "function DisplayBlurMessage(){alert('you clicked outside the textbox');}"
    scriptText &= "</script>"

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
       "BlurScript", scriptText, False)

End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the FrontEnd .aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Test Page</h3>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" columns="54" 
 Text="Click here then outside" 
 runat="server" onBlur="DisplayBlurMessage();"/>  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i view the page, clicking out of the textbox, the javascript debugger gives me an error because the javascript isn't defined in the source.

I can however get it to work by putting the Page_Load sub in  tags in the aspx file and then accessing the Attributes of the textbox directly. But this is not what I want.

Basically for my final page, I am going to want to iterate through all the textbox's on the page and then give them all a onBlur and onFocus methods that use their id's.

Is this possible? I dont see where I am going wrong.

Please help :(

Comment: I have a feeling its because its not actually being included on the aspx page, but must it always be?

Comment: Yes, you still need to add Codebehind and Inherits in page header(aspx).

Comment: I know this sounds kind of basic - but if you view source, do you see your script in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a javascript error sourcing from the line:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
       "BlurScript", scriptText, True)
```

The `True` means that the `scriptText` should be wrapped with script tags but you already have included the script tags. Either change this boolean value to False or remove the script tags ([see doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx#Y0)):

Option a:

```
Dim scriptText As String = ""
scriptText &= "function DisplayBlurMessage(){alert('you clicked outside the textbox');}"

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
   "BlurScript", scriptText, True)
```

Option b:

```
Dim scriptText As String = ""
scriptText &= "<script language='javascript'>"
scriptText &= "function DisplayBlurMessage(){alert('you clicked outside the textbox');}"
scriptText &= "</script>"

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
   "BlurScript", scriptText, False)
```

Edit:

In order to register a script you need to have a ScriptManager in your page. Add the following in your form:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I already tried that, with script tags or not it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

The last parameter of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` should be **false**.

```
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
       "BlurScript", scriptText, False)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx

EDIT:
In Page header, you also need to put `CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb"` and `Inherits="yourproject.Test"`.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="yourproject.Test" %>
```

Comment: still doesn't work, I have tried with and without script tags.